# Ajax request failed to execute showing error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been using $.ajax method to call the API for validation & subsequently processing the request. I am trying to call it but the request fails each time saying following error:

```
Exception: [Exception... "The URI scheme corresponds to an unknown protocol handler"  nsresult: "0x804b0012 (NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:90/project/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js :: .send :: line 5"  data: no]
```

My code sample is this:

```
    $('#signupProcess-form').on('click', function (e) {
       var dataObject = {firstName: $('#userFirstName').val(), lastName: $('#userLastName').val(), email: $('#userEmail').val(), password: $('#userPassword').val()};
                                    console.log(dataObject);

     $.ajax({
           url:'localhost:90/project/php/scripts/validation/signup/validation-signup.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataObject,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                 submitSignupForm(dataObject);
               }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Exception: ' + errorThrown);
            }
            });
    e.preventDefault();
   });
```

What is missing here or any process that doesn't work. Need help

Comment: try url like : `url:'//localhost....`

Comment: No URI protocol i.e. add http:// before the localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better try this one uri:'http://localhost.......'

Comment: Thats right. Probably a base url failt from my side. Thanks.